# Why does Azure App Service Resiliency Report incorrectly indicate that Proactive Autoheal is disabled

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I was investigating "Auto-heal" on one of our Azure AppServices and decided to download/generate the Resiliency report. This report indicates that Auto-heal is not enabled (see first image)
[image: Azure AppService Resiliency Report screenshot]

however, on following the recommendations of the report and looking at the auto-heal setting on the AppService, it seems to be enabled already:
[image]

Is there something else which needs to be done to fully enable auto-heal, or is this simply a bug in the report generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I can see the `Auto-Heal` option as Disabled in the report even after the `Proactive Auto-Heal` option is Enabled.

- By default, the `Proactive Auto-Heal` is Enabled when the App is created.
- As mentioned in this [azure.github.io](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2017/08/17/Introducing-Proactive-Auto-Heal.html), Another Option to Enable Auto-Heal is by setting the Environment Variable `WEBSITE_PROACTIVE_AUTOHEAL_ENABLED` to `True`.

[image]

- I have Observed that the value of `WEBSITE_PROACTIVE_AUTOHEAL_ENABLED` is changing based on the Enable and Disable option of `Proactive Auto-Heal`, but the report still shows the option as Enabled.
- The Auto-Heal Option is shown as Enabled in the report only if the `Custom Auto-Heal Rules Enabled`.

***Report:***
[image]

- You can check the `Auto-Heal check` option for more details.
- It does not have any options related to the `Proactive Auto-Heal`.

[image]

- Even I have checked it by restarting the app.

> or is this simply a bug in the report generation?

AFAIK, this is a bug in the report which shows the incorrect status of `Proactive Auto-Heal`.